# Merge two models with one-to-one relationship into one model serializer (Django)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest, I have a model named `User` which is used as `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. In order to expand this model and separate authentication-related fields with additional information, I have created another model named `Profile`. `Profile` contains unrelated data like `age`, `height`, `country`, `zip_code`, and so on. These two models have one-to-one relationship. I need a special endpoint which is only accessed by admin and used for creating a user and its profile in one request. For this purpose, I need a **flat** serailizer like this:

```json
{
    "username": "something",
    "password": "1234",
    "email": "user@domain.com",
    "age": 43,
    "country": "USA"
}
```

I tried creating a class inheriting `serailizers.Serializer` and create fields manually, but this seems very unengineered. Also imagine what happens if later on I add new fields to these models.

Also, I could include `ProfileSerializer` inside `UserSerializer` and I would have:

```json
{
    "username": "something",
    "password": "1234",
    "email": "user@domain.com",
    "profile": {
                   "country": "USA",
                   // and rest of fields
                }
}
```

But this example is NOT what I need.

I need a **flat** serializer combining two (or even more) models that have one-to-one relationship.The serializer must contain all required fields of these two models. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to specify the fields for your related model in the serializer.

Your profile class is probably as below(most standard way):

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

The follwing serializer gives you a flat json:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    age = serializers.IntegerField(source="profile.age")
    country = serializers.CharField(source="profile.country")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'username',
            'email',
            'age',
            'country',
        ]
```

Comment: What if later on, I add fields to profile model? I need to manually add those fields to serailizer.

Comment: Yes of course you need. 
In fact, even you've a `ProfileSerializer`, you'll need to add the fields in the `Meta` class, unless you've `fields = ['__all__']` in the Meta class (which is a bad idea)